# SQL Select on priority of not exist

Tags: sql, select

I'm quite confused as to how I'd structure a query I need:

```
select distinct NodeID from GroupsTable
                    where GroupID in
                    (
                        select GroupID from UserGroupsTable
                        where UserID = @UserID
                    )
```

I need to select NodeID from GroupsTable where the User belongs to multiple groups, **UNLESS** any group that the user belongs to does not have that NodeID.

The above code only selects a NodeID from GroupsTable where it apears in any one of the users groups.

So:

> Group|Node
>
> 1|A
>   1|B
>   2|A

I need only B to be selected for example.

Any Ideas?

Comment: So you want to select `NodeID` if it is shared by all groups the user belongs to?

Comment: Would putting it another way be: "I need to select all Nodes which are part of every group a user belongs to"?

Comment: `B` in your example does not belong to all groups, unlike `A`. Why do you want to select `B` and not `A`?

Comment: Can you give sample data in both the tables to clarify it more? Based on that we can try making required query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @UserID int
select G.NodeID
from GroupsTable G
inner join
(
    select GroupID, count(*) over () GroupCount
    from UserGroupsTable
    where UserID = @UserID
) UG on UG.GroupID = G.GroupID
GROUP BY G.NodeID, UG.GroupCount
HAVING COUNT(*) != UG.GroupCount OR UG.GroupCount = 1
-- count=1 is special. it will always equal groupcount, but let it through
```

(assuming this is SQL Server and version >= 2005 for using the count(*) over)

@answer HAVING condition changed following comments

Comment: Thanks for your effort - Your select was almost right, but did the inverse of what was required. It selected the NodeID that was in all Groups instead of selecting the NodeID present in only some groups(but not all)

Comment: @Ted - "inverse" - isn't that as simple as changing the last row to != ?

Comment: Indeed - but I found that "having count(*) <> UG.GroupCount" works perfectly for more than 1 group, but if a user is only in 1 group it returns nothing - when it should return all nodeID's for that single group. It's probably quite simple to change, but i'm terrible at sql as i'm sure you've guessed. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `having` clause to ensure that the count of groups per node is less than the count of all groups the user is in:

```
select  g.NodeID
from    GroupsTable g
join    UserGroupsTable ug 
on      g.GroupID = ug.GroupID
where   ug.UserID = 1
group by
        ug.UserID
,       g.NodeID
having  COUNT(distinct g.GroupID) < 
        (
        select  COUNT(distinct GroupID) 
        from    UserGroupsTable ug2 
        where   ug2.UserID = ug.UserID
        )
```

Comment: AKA relational division, http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Comment: if you group by g.NodeID, isn't count(distinct g.NodeID) = 1?

Comment: @Ted - strange.. this achieves the same outcome as my answer "present in all groups" which you commented as "inverse of requirement". the same solution of course to inverse the test